# Simon Game : Two colors in a row won't fade properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a javascript 'Simon says' game.
So far, I made some basic tests with buttons. 
First button 'Start' generates a sequence. Second button 'Show' will show what was generated.
Everything works except when the same color, in the random generated sequence, appears in a row.

Ex: = [ 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow']

Only in this case the fade-in / fade-out effect won't work.
I checked with DevTools, what was wrong and it seems that the loop adds the class 'fade-out' to both indexes (in the case above..to index 1 and 2).

Why is that? And how can I fix it?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="blue" class="btn"></div>
  <div id="red" class="btn"></div>
  <div id="yellow" class="btn"></div>
  <div id="green" class="btn"></div>
</div>

<button id="startBtn">Start</button>
<button id='showMe'>Show</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 25vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.fade-out {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#red {
  background-color: red;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

**JS**

```
var color = container.querySelectorAll('div.btn');
var startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
var showBtn = document.getElementById('showMe');

var pcSequence = [],
    mySequence = [],
    i,
    theLoop;

startBtn.addEventListener('click', oneMore, false);
showBtn.addEventListener('click', showSeq, false);

function oneMore(){
  pcSequence.push(color[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);
}

function showSeq(){
  i = 0;
  theLoop = setInterval(function(){
    if (i > 0){ pcSequence[i - 1].classList.remove('fade-out'); }
    if (i >= pcSequence.length){
      clearInterval(theLoop);
    } else {
      pcSequence[i].classList.add('fade-out');
    }
    i++;
  }, 2000);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not seeing the problem with fade-out appearing on two of the squares, I do see that, for example, in your case of blue, yellow, yellow, the yellow isn't doesn't become unfaded-out at all.

If that is the problem you are concerned about, the reason is that you are removing the class and then immediately re-adding it, so the ui is essentially not doing the fade-in.

Another strategy here might be to use the transitionend event to do the fade in, rather than doing that in the interval.  Something like this (I put a hack in to force the red and yellow to be set each time):

```js
var color = container.querySelectorAll('div.btn');
var startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
var showBtn = document.getElementById('showMe');

var pcSequence = [],
    mySequence = [],
    i,
    theLoop;

startBtn.addEventListener('click', oneMore, false);
showBtn.addEventListener('click', showSeq, false);

// Force red initially
pcSequence.push(color[1]);
function oneMore(){
  // Force yellow each time they press Start
  pcSequence.push(color[2]);
   //Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);
}

function clearTransition() {
 var colorSquare = pcSequence[i - 1];
    colorSquare.removeEventListener('transitionend', clearTransition);
 colorSquare.classList.remove('fade-out');
}

function showSeq(){
  i = 0;
  theLoop = setInterval(function(){
    if (i >= pcSequence.length){
      clearInterval(theLoop);
    } else {
      var colorSquare = pcSequence[i];
 
      colorSquare.classList.add('fade-out');
      colorSquare.addEventListener('transitionend', clearTransition);
    }
    i++;
  }, 2000);  
}
```

```css
.btn {
  height: 100px;
  width: 25vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.fade-out {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#red {
  background-color: red;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="blue" class="btn"></div>
  <div id="red" class="btn"></div>
  <div id="yellow" class="btn"></div>
  <div id="green" class="btn"></div>
</div>

<button id="startBtn">Start</button>
<button id='showMe'>Show</button>
```